Wordpress and MariaDB: Sorting (internally using inner join) doesn't work?
I use WAMP on my dev machine running MariaDB. On the server I use MySQL. The main page is a list of events sorted by a metavalue: event_date. Here's the query as generated by Wordpress
SELECT   wp_posts.ID, wp_postmeta.meta_value
                    FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
                    WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'event_date_time' 
  AND 
  ( 
    ( 
      ( mt1.meta_key = 'event_date_time' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS DATE) >= '2024-04-09' )
    )
  )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'tc_events' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
                    GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
                    ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value ASC
                    LIMIT 0, 200;

This is vanilla Wordpress WP_Query using args.
Works fine on the server (Ubuntu/Apache/MySQL). But on the laptop, running MariaDB, the Order By is ignored. Poking around the intarwebs, seems like MariaDB adheres to SQL standards more rigorously and there are issues with Order By. But everything on the very same intarwebs says that MariaDB is just fine for Wordpress?

since when do joins order, the don't, they start at the beginning of the left table and go through th second snf so on, it may be that you have unintentionally he "correct order" what ever that is. in essence tables and resultsets are by nature unsorted and only an order by can sort it

and the whole parenthesis should be removed they don't serve any purpose

can you provide a fiddle example?

To double clarify, this is not my query. This is generated by Wordpress WP_Query. In this case, the "ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value ASC" is honored on the MySQL database and ignored by the MariaDB database.

Technically WordPress should work fine with MariaDB, and the query should have produced the same result on both MySql and MariaDB. you would need to verify if there is any version conflict https://make.wordpress.org/hosting/handbook/compatibility/#wordpress-php-mysql-mariadb-versions
MariaDB tends to be stricter with queries using GROUP BY and ORDER BY together. In MariaDB, you need to include all non-aggregated columns from the SELECT clause in the GROUP BY clause.
So try changing your GROUP BY clause
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID,wp_postmeta.meta_value


Can you provide an example? - in this simple example you can.

The WAMP machine is running MariaDB 10.5.4 and the Ubuntu is running MySQL 8.0.36. The code (and the query) is identical on both machines. On MariaDB, it sorts by wp_posts.ID, ignoring the "Order By" clause. Adding the wp_postmeta.meta_value to the Group By does nothing. But changing this Wordpress code would not be trivial. I guess there's just not many people running MariaDB with plugins that order by meta_value? Because it just doesn't work.

The query JOINs to wp_postmeta twice.  The one to use in ORDER BY is ambiguous.  The following may fix that and numerous other issues:
SELECT  wp_posts.ID, mt1.meta_value
    FROM  wp_posts
    INNER JOIN  wp_postmeta AS mt1  ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
    WHERE  mt1.meta_key = 'event_date_time'
      AND  mt1.meta_value >= '2024-04-09'
      AND  wp_posts.post_type = 'tc_events'
      AND  wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
    ORDER BY  mt1.meta_value ASC
    LIMIT  0, 200;

Notes:

The GROUP BY seems useless (or maybe incorrect)
This assumes that dates are stored in mt1 in syntax like '2024-04-09...'
This plugin should help with performance:  WP Index Improvements


I'm not tryna by ornery, but my point is getting lost. I guess I can't post code in a comment, otherwise I would post the actual Wordpress PHP code used by this plugin which is just a series of args to for a call to WP_Query( $args ). Most WP code avoids direct SQL queries (as it should). But as in the other comment from @nbk where they complain about unnec. parens, THIS IS NOT MY QUERY! It's not even SQL from the author of the plugin. This is a SQL query generated by Wordpress which is "supposed" to work with MariaDB and clearly does NOT.

@jeromio - Frameworks have flaws.  Sometimes, the solution is to provide a better formulation of the query, and some frameworks let you do that.
